# Are Netflix documentaries sometimes re-edited after the initial broadcast?

Tags: alternate-version, netflix

I have re-watched two Netflix documentaries in the recent past that made me think that the version the second time around was different to the original.

The first one that made me think this was "Wild Wild Country". The music seemed different and also the editing.

The second one was "The Andy Warhol Diaries". In the last episode a person was describing an event but their words and emotions seemed different, as though though the editing of the interview had changed. Also, some parts of that episode I don't recall from the first viewing.

Is it possible that some Netflix documentaries are re-edited after the initial broadcast?

Answer (score 5):

"*Is it possible that some Netflix documentaries are re-edited after the initial broadcast?*": it happens all the time, for TV shows and movies. It's not Netflix related. Some documentaries or movies need more extra postproduction work sometimes, to correct facts or numbers, translation, lenght, or better stick to different artistic choices.

> Re-editing scenes and portions of shows and movies isn't a new concept and has been in practice for years. And while creators think the process of re-editing makes their original stories stronger, many fans reject the idea and prefer movies and shows to stay in their original formats. Despite what fans want, Hollywood and the creatives behind it continue to change movie films for a variety of different reasons. from [Screenrant - 10 Shows & Movies that have been edited after their original release](https://screenrant.com/tv-shows-films-edited-after-original-release/)

More to read:

1. [12 Sundance films that were re-edited or retitled after their Festival Premieres](https://www.mtv.com/news/qupfl4/re-edited-or-retitled-sundance-movies)
2. [Art of the Cut: conversations with film and TV editors](https://books.google.fr/books?id=VTIlDwAAQBAJ&pg=PR17&lpg=PR17#v=onepage&q&f=false)
3. [Manipulative Editing](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ManipulativeEditing)
4. [Spike Lee Re-Edits HBO Sept. 11 Series](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/08/25/arts/television/spike-lee-911-conspiracy-theorists.html)
5. [Honest Truths: documentary filmmakers on ethical challenges in their work](https://cmsimpact.org/resource/honest-truths-documentary-filmmakers-on-ethical-challenges-in-their-work/)<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Here are some thoughts that may lead to editing, because they occur ***after*** the release. "*Controversies emerged about several documentaries. Was Fahrenheit 9/11 accurate in its factual indictment of the Bush administration's geopolitics? Did Mighty Times: The Children's March misrepresent civil rights history through its use of both fabricated and repurposed archival evidence? Should films such as Ghosts of Abu Ghraib and Standard Operating Procedure feature images that further embarrass and humiliate their subjects?*"

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way of knowing if a doc has changed? Do the broadcasters not need to give out that information? In journal articles there is often an editor's note to say something was changed.

Comment: I have no information about that, but I'm probably sure filmmakers with strong ethics would put a disclaimer upfront, explaining what and why they modified/updated. I don't think it would be relevant when you just talk about minor aesthetic or artistic differences. They may release a statement, or explain in an interview like G. Lucas did. Edit and release another version on DVD.